# No data after scraping a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape all names from a website [https://www.internationaltelecomsweek.com](http://internationaltelecomweek.com) using Scrapy.

This is in the item file.

```
import scrapy
class ItwItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
```

This is my spider.

```
import scrapy
from itw.items import ItwItem
class ItwSpider(scrapy.Spider):

        name = 'itw'

        allowed_domains = ['https://www.internationaltelecomsweek.com']

        start_urls = ['https://www.internationaltelecomsweek.com/this-year/companies-attending']

        def parse(self, response):
        data= json.loads(response.body)
        for i in data:
        item["name"] = i["DisplayName"]
        return item
```

When I run scrapy I only get a blank csv file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the list of attendees is dynamically generated and each attendee returned as a JSON-object.

Load up the site in the `scrapy shell` and check `view(response)` to see what your spider can actually read. You'll see that the page returns nothing where in your browser you can see the attendees.

If you check the network-tab to see which requests are being passed to the server, you'll see that the list of attendees are being passed from [this URL](https://www.internationaltelecomsweek.com/api/eventcompaniesapi/list?eventid=), each as a JSON-object.

What you'll have to do is: Parse the URL which yields the JSON-objects and process them using JSON in scrapy:

```
import json

data = json.loads(response.body)
for i in data:
    item["name"] = i["DisplayName"]
```

Comment: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Means that your indentation is not correct. The example code I posted should be under your parse-function, which means that you should indent it 8 spaces.

Comment: Edit your improved code in your original post and format it as you have it. Indentation is not shown in comments.